# Trabalhando com git em modo gráfico no windows

Tags: git, windows, github

Tenho o git rodando em uma rede interna.
Quero permitir uma das estações a trabalhar nesse servidor.
Já gerei a chave nessa estação e adicionei no servidor onde tem o git.
Já criei a repositorio no servidor e preciso agora que essa estação envie todo o projeto pra esse novo repositorio (que está vazio).
A estação já tem o github instalado. (essa estação é windows)
Como fazer o `git init` em uma pasta que esta dentro de `Windows/wamp/projeto`?
Abri o git gui nessa maquina windows mas ele não me mostra a opção de apontar o repositorio remoto. No meu caso, o repositorio esta em `git@10.0.0.200:~/projects/myproject.git`

Comment: Até onde sei, a forma mais fácil seria fazer um **git clone** do seu projeto que já está no servidor fazendo com que criasse um diretório vazio mas versionado. Depois disso você passa os arquivos que você já tem pra esse diretório versionado faz um **commit** e **push**.

Comment: A pergunta é relacionada a uma pasta já existente, com um projeto já existente e de preferencia utilizando o git gui.

Comment: OK, posso ter entendido errado, mas pelo que entendi você tem todo o projeto em uma máquina da rede, porém, esse projeto ainda não está versionado com o git. Fez todo o processo de criar o repositório no servidor e falta fazer com que os arquivos da máquina contendo o projeto sejam versionados no repositório criado, correto?

Comment: Exato.. E de preferencia, queria fazer isso em modo grafico. Pois precisarei depois instruir aos desenvolvedores a fazerem o mesmo procedimento. E ainda existe uma certa resistencia no modo texto na empresa.

Comment: Certo. Então se você colocar todos os seus arquivos dentro do diretório que foi criado com o **git clone**, depois de dentro do diretório executar um **git gui**, irá aparecer a opção de efetuar um **commit** dos arquivos não versionados e alterados, fazendo o commit fica faltando o **push** pra deixar efetivamente no servidor.

Assim, da próxima vez que alguém fizer o clone do projeto todos os arquivos virão com o diretório, e caso alterações sejam feitas e precisem ser enviadas para o servidor é só repetir o processo de **git gui**, **commit** e **push**. Deve funcionar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você já tem o repositório em seu computador você pode criar um *remote* que aponte para servidor remoto (seu servidor windows no caso) e depois dar um *push*. Desta forma:

**Usando o console**

- *(Opcional)* No console, use o comando *git remote -v*. Isso vai mostrar todos os URL de onde você pode dar um clone. Note que você vai ver uma linha chamada *orign* que segue um padrão diferente, todos os hosts que seguirem este padrão são hosts para onde você pode submeter atualizações;
- Use o comando *git remote add [nome-servidor] [url]*, onde [nome-servidor] é apenas um alias para facilitar a identificação do seu servidor. Use o nome que achar mais conveniente;
- Finalmente, use o comando *git push [nome-servidor] [branch]*, onde nome-servidor é o alias do servidor remoto que você escolheu no passo anterior e [branch] é a revisão que você quer enviar (use *master* caso queira enviar a raiz).

Você pode ler mais sobre remotes neste link: http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/Git-Essencial-Trabalhando-com-Remotos

**Atualização - Trabalhar com modo gráfico:**

**Usando o Git-Gui**

1 - Abra o seu repositório local:
[image: Abrir repositorio]

2 - Use o menu Remoto -> Add
[image: Add Remoto]

3 - Dê um nome para o Remoto e depois coloque a URL SSH. Lembre-se de configurar seu git-gui e informar suas credenciais de acesso. Marque a opção 'Não fazer nada' (Isso apenas para o caso de você querer enviar uma primeira revisão para o server) e depois clique em Adicionar.
[image: Adicionando Remoto]

4 - Depois envie sua cópia para o servidor. 
[image: Push]

**Usando o Tortoise SVN**

É possível usar o tortoise svn para trabalhar com o Git (Eu uso no Github, não sei se vai funcionar no seu caso, mas tente)

1 - Num diretório vazio, use o svn checkout.
[image: SVN Checkout]

2 - Use o url Https do seu repositório
[image: url]

3 - Faça o checkout. Repare que o svn vai criar uma pasta trunk e uma branches. Seu 'master' estará no 'trunk'

[image: diretorios]

4 - Jogue o conteúdo de seu repositório no diretório que você criou e dê um commit.
[image: commit]

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Edgar, nos comentários acho que deixei claro que a necessidade da empresa a qual trabalho seria uma solução em modo gráfico. A forma que apresentou eu já conheço. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz editei minha resposta e coloquei como se faz em modo gráfico.

Comment: Não sabia que o tortoise trabalhava com git. Muito obrigado pela atenção e reposta explicativa.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz Não é o melhor dos mundos. Eu uso no trabalho por causa do proxy. Em casa uso o RabbitVCS. Existe também o GitEye, da collab.net, ele é bem legal.

Comment: Existe o [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) também, acredito que seja mais adequado que o TortoiseSVN, alias existe port do TortoiseSVN para Mercurial e CVS, talvez até para algum outro que eu não conheça

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa Muito interessante, vou experimentar. O mais importante neste caso é entender o funcionamento do Git. Sabendo disso a pessoa será capaz de usar por linha de comando ou Gui sem problemas.